# How to select folder using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

i want select folder using asp.net , when i click browse button it will open file selection dialog.

Comment: Do you mean a folder selection, or a file selection?

Comment: folder or multiple file selection.

Answer (score 2):

There is no html control for folder selection - so this is not possible with ASP.Net.

Comment: any other method is there for selecting folder using any client script or plugin using asp.net.

i used javascript activeX but it supported only IE

Comment: For a portable solution you would need a plug-in like Flash or Java Applet. Even then however, your plug-in should be granted special rights. Accessing a system folder from the browser is considered an unsafe operation.

Answer (score -1):

You Can Add:

1- Folder Browser Dialog (For Folder)
     and use it Like This:

```
    `if(folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
         string str = DialogFolderBrows.SelectedPath;`
```

2- Open File Dialog (For File)
     and use it Like This:

```
   `if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
         string str = DialogOpenFile.FileName;`
```

Comment: it is not supported for asp.net ,
so you know how to support folderbrowser dialog in web page.
if you know plz explain