# Select a folder in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, directory

I have a web application in which I need to allow users to select a folder, much like folderbrowserdialog. I can't use file upload control because I don't need to select any files.

This is for allowing users to select a folder and click on "Archive" button where all files in selected folder will be moved to a pre-determined archive folder and marked in DB as such.

Is this possible in a web application? If folder has 20 files, i don't want to ask the user to select each one separately and archive it.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed example of the wanted end result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select folder using ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897189/how-to-select-folder-using-asp-net)

Comment: If the folder they are selecting is from a shared drive which the web server has access to or is a folder on the web server, Build a display of this directory on your web page, let user select the folder from page, else As mentioned in the duplicate marked by Sinatr there is no native control for a web page for selecting a directory folder.

Comment: OK, seems this cannot be done in a web application. To answer Avi, I have a document management applications and some files/folders that get too old need to be moved to an archive folder. I wanted the user to be able to select a folder whose entire content needs to be archived rather than selecting single files from said folder.

Answer (score 0):

I used this api a while ago for visual change on an organization tree. Pretty sure it would fit your requirement since allows multiple object selection and drag and drop.

https://github.com/vakata/jstree

All the documentation you need and examples are on the page.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out.

Comment: No, it looks like some weird fantasy management with no actual access to folders and files. How is this possible that with such a big push for web applications, we still cannot select a folder in 2022?